# Using if [ -s /logfilepath ] and being true when file is blank and 0 bytes

Tags: bash

Here is what my current code is and haven't been able to figure out a solution. So here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

date_time=$(date +%s)

file_output=$(ls -l --time-style=long-iso /data/ | grep drwxrwxrwx | awk '{print $6,$7","$8","}')

rm -rf /tmp/tmp_direc_last_update.log
echo "$file_output > /tmp/tmp_direc_last_update.log

if [ -s /tmp/tmp_direc_update.log ]
then
   sed -e "s/$/""$date_time"",/" -i /tmp/tmp_direc_last_update.log
   final_file=$(cat /tmp/tmp_direc_last_update.log) 
   echo "$final_file" > /data/stats/direc_last_update.log
else
   exit
fi
```

What I need to do is to check if the /tmp/tmp_direc_last_update.log is empty and if it is, don't execute any of the code in the if/then statement. Using ShellCheck, I know that I shouldn't be using ls | grep, but all the folders that need to be looked at are numerical only.

When I run the code line by line, the rm removes the file before I put it back, but in the case of file_output, if it outputs nothing, then I want it to NOT run the code in the if statement. But when the  "if [ -s /tmp/tmp_direc_update.log ]" checks to see if the file exists and is greater than 0 bytes, it says it's true, but it's not because it's a blank file. Am I misunderstanding something?

My linux bash scripting skills are not that great, so any help anyone could assist with would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You're missing a quote on the `echo "$file_output` line.

Comment: `[ -s file ]` should indeed be false if the file is empty. However, it's _never_ going to be empty if you have an `echo "$something" >` to that file on a line just before

Comment: ...because even if `"$something"` is empty, that `echo` is going to write a newline, so there will always be at least one byte.

Comment: Anyhow -- if you're convinced that `test -s` is misbehaving, please provide a test case that conclusively demonstrates that misbehavior. `> somefile; test -s somefile; echo "Exit status: $?"` is probably the shortest possible case, but it correctly shows `Exit status: 1`.

Comment: Why don't you just check whether `$file_output` is empty? `if [ -n "$file_output" ]`

Comment: BTW, when you double up double quotes they cancel each other out. `sed -e "s/$/""$date_time"",/"` is **exactly** the same as `sed -e "s/$/$date_time,/"`.

Comment: ...if you want the inner quotes to be part of the data `sed` matches, that would instead look like `sed -e "s/$/\"$date_time\",/"` -- though I would instead write it as `sed -e 's/$/"'"$date_time"'",/'`

Comment: @testy, ...btw, `777` permissions should basically never be used, by anyone, for anything whatsoever. Letting completely untrusted user accounts like `nobody` write to a file that other, more-privileged users are allowed to execute is a fast route to getting your box 0wned.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the immediate problem is the filenames. You remove and create `/tmp/tmp_direc_last_update.log`:

```sh
rm -rf /tmp/tmp_direc_last_update.log
echo "$file_output" > /tmp/tmp_direc_last_update.log
```

... but then check for the size of `/tmp/tmp_direc_update.log`:

```sh
if [ -s /tmp/tmp_direc_update.log ]
```

The immediate fix is: change your `if` line to match the file you just created:

```sh
if [ -s /tmp/tmp_direc_last_update.log ]
```

Additionally, instead of attempting to parse the output of `ls`, you could gather the same output with the `find` command:

```sh
find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -type d -perm 777 -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM,%f,\n'
```

Comment: Jeesh, I didn't see the 777 permissions. That's awful.